# Including a module and calling one of its functions from within another module in Julia

Tags: struct, module, namespaces, load, julia

Let's say I have a module, Module1 defining a struct and a fit() function. I have another module, call it Parent, that includes Module1 and defines a test() function that also calls fit(). If I define the structure from Module 1 and then call test() from Parent I'm having trouble with the namespaces. Here's the code for this example:

```
#this module would be in a separate file
module Module1
    struct StructMod1
    end
    export StructMod1
    function fit(s::StructMod1)
    end
    export fit
end

module Parent
    #including the module with include("Module1.jl")
    module Module1
        struct StructMod1
        end
        export StructMod1
        function fit(s::StructMod1)
        end
        export fit
    end
    #including the exports from the module
    using .Module1
    function test(s::StructMod1)
        fit(s)
        return s
    end
    export test
end

using .Parent, .Module1

s = Parent.Module1.StructMod1()
@show test(s)
s2 = StructMod1()
@show test(s2)
```

And the output

```
test(s) = Main.Parent.Module1.StructMod1()
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching test(::StructMod1)
Closest candidates are:
  test(::Main.Parent.Module1.StructMod1)
```

Alternatively, if I replace using .Module1 with using ..Module1 then the definition of s2 works. But then, when calling using .Parent I have to make sure that Module1 is already loaded.

What is the best way to define a struct with one module and then use it with another module's functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double include is causing the error. In your example, `Parent.Module1` is not the same as `Module1`. Its useful to think of `include` as a dumb copy/paste. Even though they share the same source file, the double include makes them appear as two different modules (as your example shows).

The solution is to `include` only once and use [relative imports](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Relative-and-absolute-module-paths-1) to refer to the module.

As for organizing the whole set of modules, I like to `include` all the modules sequentially in the main module and then use relative imports where needed. I find this to be the simplest approach.

The final version would look something like this:

```
# Module1.jl
module Module1
    struct StructMod1
    end
    export StructMod1
    function fit(s::StructMod1)
    end
    export fit
end
```

```
# Parent.jl
module Parent
    using ..Module1
    function test(s::StructMod1)
        fit(s)
        return s
    end
    export test
end
```

```
#Main.jl
include("Module1.jl")
include("Parent.jl")

using .Parent, .Module1

s = Parent.Module1.StructMod1()
@show test(s)
s2 = StructMod1()
@show test(s2)
```

Comment: (or, of course, the other way is also valid, defining `Module1` _only_ in `Parent`, and writing `using .Parent, .Parent.Module1` in Main.) Both are reasonable! :)